# How to get the current directory from the whole path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

With:

```
currentPath = pathlib.Path.cwd()
```

I get the current path:

```
/path/to/my/location/
```

How can I get the directory `location` without the need to manually process the complete path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've linked a duplicate to your question. But if you are asking for `pathlib` specific solution, use [`name`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name) field:

```
currentPath = pathlib.Path.cwd().name
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just simply use `split()`:

```py
import os

pwd = os.getcwd()
print(pwd.split("/")[-1])
```

[edited] more robust solutions and works cross-platform by 
[@Yevhen Kuzmovych](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4727702/yevhen-kuzmovych)

```py
import os

pwd = os.getcwd()
head, tail = os.path.split(pwd)
print(tail)
```

Comment: Using `os.path.split` is more robust.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych yeah you're right